# GWT favicon.ico returning error!(GWT and Java)

Tags: java, gwt, icons, saxparser

My program, (Basically the GWT Sample Code, except with different headers and names) was working *perfect* - until I added a `favicon.ICO` file and `<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`! Now my program returns:

`[WARN] Unable to process '.../war/WEB-INF/web.xml' for servlet validation`

```
org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.JAXPFactory.setFeature(JAXPFactory.java:102)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.ServletValidator.create(ServletValidator.java:188)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.ServletValidator.create(ServletValidator.java:172)
    ...
```

`[ERROR] Failure while parsing XML`

```
org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd
    at gnu.xml.aelfred2.JAXPFactory.setFeature(JAXPFactory.java:102)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:324)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
    ...
```

`[ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML`

```
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:355)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:402)
```

`[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method`

I have now **removed** `favicon.ICO`, and my program is ***still*** returning the same error!

Is the problem with the **code**, or with the `favicon`?
I am using the GWT Eclipse Plugin

I am ***REALLY*** confused!!! Can any body **please** help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gnu.xml.aelfred2` in the stacktrace rings a bell: have you changed anything to your classpath? or put gnujaxp.jar in your `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext`? (see http://www.gnu.org/software/classpathx/jaxp/) or switched JRE/JDK?

It's clear that GWT thinks it's talking to Apache Xerces (which BTW is the Reference Implementation for JAXP, and the one included in the Sun/Oracle JRE/JDK and in OpenJDK), but your JVM gives it a GNU Ælfred2 implementation instead.
Additionally, `gwt-dev.jar` *bundles* Xerces, so the only reason you're using Ælfred2 is because of a classpath or boot-classpath issue.

Comment: No, I have not changed anything in my `CLASSPATH` System Variable.

Comment: @Java I've edited my answer with more info, check it out; hope it'll solve your issue.

Comment: My `CLASSPATH` and `Path` look fine (I am using `Windows XP`). I am not a very experienced programmer, could you tell me what to expect? Should I have something about `GWT` in it? My `CLASSPATH` is `.;` and my `PATH` is `H:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32...`.

Comment: The classpath is built from your Eclipse project "Build Path", not the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. The `Path` environment variable is not used; your Eclipse configured JRE is (look at your launcher configuration for the DevMode in Eclipse). Finally, look into `H:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\ext` (assuming it's the JRE used by your Eclipse project) if there's a `gnujaxp.jar` (or similar)

Comment: There is _not_ a `gnujaxp.jar`, so I have added it. `gnujaxp.jar` is already on my `Build Path`. Now it is giving me the ***same errors***!

Comment: Of course! `gnujaxp.jar` *is* causing the errors. So either you had it to your build path (but you said you didn't change your classpath, so I assumed it wasn't the issue), or you had it in your `jre\lib\ext`. Remove `gnujaxp.jar` from your build path, at least for GWT's DevMode and Compiler launches (it shouldn't be an issue to  use it for your server-side code)

Comment: ***THANK YOU*** _very much!!!_ `gunjaxp.jar` _was_ the problem! My program works fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that GWT cannot find xerces. I had the same problem but couldn't find gnujaxp.jar on my classpath. I dropped xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar into the web-inf/lib folder and it started working.

Comment: As said in Thomas Broyer's answer `gwt-dev.jar` _bundles_ Xerces so I already have it. I'm guessing GWT was using Ælfred2 because of `gnujaxp.jar`.

Comment: Yes - it _does_ bundle it but the GWT library still finds gnujaxp **first**. It seems I avoided the problem by adding the Xerces library. The likely reason is because that Xerces library is loaded before the GWT library. When the time the GWT library looks Xerces it is provided with the loaded one.